Google slide shape copy problem using appscript
There is 1 shape that I created in Google Slide, and it creates as many copies on the page as I want to create from index.html.
My real question is, 10 copies fit on 1 page. 11. The copying process should continue from the 2nd page, but in this function, the copying process continues from the 1st page.
Note copying positions are available in the code, the same positions are also valid for the 2nd, 3rd and 4th pages.
function copyShapes(copyCount) {
  const presentation = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
  let slide = presentation.getSlides()[0];
  const group = slide.getGroups()[0];


  const duplicatedGroup = group.duplicate();

 
  group.remove();

  const xIncrement = 10; // x artış oranı
  const yIncrement = 5;  // y artış oranı
  const initialX = 0;
  const initialY = 0.5;
  const maxCopiesPerPage = 10;

  for (let i = 0; i < copyCount; i++) {
    if (i % maxCopiesPerPage === 0) {
      // Yeni bir sayfa ekle ve slide değişkenini güncelle
      if (i > 0) {
        slide = presentation.appendSlide(SlidesApp.PredefinedLayout.BLANK);
      }
    }

    const positionIndex = i % maxCopiesPerPage;

    const row = Math.floor(positionIndex / 2);
    const col = positionIndex % 2;

    const x = cmToPoints(initialX + col * xIncrement);
    const y = cmToPoints(initialY + row * yIncrement);

   
    const newGroup = duplicatedGroup.duplicate();
    newGroup.setLeft(x).setTop(y);
  }


  duplicatedGroup.remove();
}



I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1qFbwRUB4aCnfpMGIhMc_eCpKEMTZPkqHH52khxDJh6o/edit?usp=sharing
First of all, I give the link address.
There is 1 shape in my project, I enter how many copies I want to create from index.html, for example, when I ask for 5 copies, it gives 5 copies. (I gave the locations of the copies of the figures as coordinates in the codes respectively). 10 copies fit on each page. My problem is when I want to enter 12 copies, 10 of them fit on the first page, but the remaining 2 are not copied to the second page and continue to copy on the 1st page.

and script code
https://script.google.com/u/0/home/projects/13-f6TrIUFYpN1qtkITIgX4-zd1fDtTTsJkDSMgkSiOjX_aibaVjQhG3Z/edit

note: shapes are grouped

Thank you for replying and providing the sample Google Slide. From them, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your expected result, I apologize.

Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your expected result, from your reply, how about the following modification? In this modification, your function copyShapes is modified.
Modified script:
function copyShapes(copyCount) {
  const presentation = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
  const slide = presentation.getSlides()[0];
  let group = slide.getGroups()[0];
  const xIncrement = 10;
  const yIncrement = 5;
  const initialX = 0;
  const initialY = 0.5;
  const maxCopiesPerPage = 10;
  for (let i = 0; i < copyCount; i++) {
    if (i % maxCopiesPerPage === 0) {
      if (i > 0) {
        group = presentation.appendSlide(SlidesApp.PredefinedLayout.BLANK).insertGroup(group);
      }
    } else {
      const positionIndex = i % maxCopiesPerPage;
      const row = Math.floor(positionIndex / 2);
      const col = positionIndex % 2;
      const x = cmToPoints(initialX + col * xIncrement);
      const y = cmToPoints(initialY + row * yIncrement);
      group.duplicate().setLeft(x).setTop(y);
    }
  }
}


When I tested this modified script using your provided Google Slide, I confirmed that when I use 12 with copyCount, 2 groups are put into the 2nd slide.


It says {{NAME1}} in each copied group. How can I change the number of copies to {{NAME1}}, {{NAME2}},{{NAME3}}?

@Esat Kurtul Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question It says {{NAME1}} in each copied group. How can I change the number of copies to {{NAME1}}, {{NAME2}},{{NAME3}}?, I would like to suport you. But, that is a different question from your this question. So, can you post it as a new question by including more information? By posting it as a new question, users including me can think of it. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve your new question?
